# Error Code: 10001 Invalid Request - Encrypted request invalid/not present on Live

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am trying to integrate CCAvenue payment Gateway in Laravel. I followed [Integrate CCAvenue in Laravel](https://github.com/softon/indipay) exactly as described.

Also I got new access code as well as working key from CCAvenue.
Now I am facing the following error:

> Error Code: 10001 Invalid Request - Encrypted request invalid/not present. Don't worry... It happens to the best of us.

What could be wrong?

Comment: do you have the correct credentials? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611149/ccavenue-error-code-10001-invalid-request-encrypted-request-invalid-not-prese

Comment: Yeah, i got the credentials from CCAvenue.